# Toggle image by clicking link and disable the active link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage which has many divs like the one below. It uses simple javascript to toggle image by clicking on two separate links. [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RaghavTheCyberdude/a99nnmbw/).

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   <div class="caption">
      <h4>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleImg0('test')">Image1</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleImg1('test')">Image2</a>
        </h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
function toggleImg1(charName) {
   document.getElementById(charName).getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "http://placehold.it/150x150";
}

function toggleImg0(charName) {
   document.getElementById(charName).getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "http://placehold.it/100x100";
}
```

Now, I want to disable the link whose corresponding image is displayed (it should be like normal text). How can I do so?

Have a look at the complete webpage [here](http://teraflik.com/projects/the-flash/characters/all.html).

Comment: Use CSS `background-image` property. And just toggle the class

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery? You have the jQuery tag but you're not using jQuery functions to access the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using JQuery so why not using his functions, give your links a global class `toggle_img` then you can use **[data attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** to define the `src` you want every link to change when it's clicked, finally define  `click` event and change the `src` attribute using **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** function, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('body').on('click', '.toggle_img', function() {
  $('img').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <div class="caption">
    <h4>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle_img" data-src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>Image1</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle_img" data-src='http://placehold.it/150x150'>Image2</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Change the link of active image to simple text by adding extra css classes, e.g :

```js
$('body').on('click', '.toggle_img', function() {
  $('img').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));

  if (!$(this).hasClass("active"))
    $(this).addClass('active');

  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.toggle_link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer
}

.active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <div class="caption">
    <h4>
      <span class="active toggle_link toggle_img" data-src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>Image1</span>
      <span class="toggle_link toggle_img" data-src='http://placehold.it/150x150'>Image2</span>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also need some script to change the link of active image to simple text. Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is another solution**

**Instead of creating two functions for each anchor tags, you can create one onclick handler function**

Example

```
<script>
function toggleImg(charName,obj) {
    var image=document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    //store image1 and image2 href
    var img_source1= "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7j4zeqZB4theKrjb13e8XwhXXYpumwYEzTvhYclxrSrzS_5yJ";
    var img_source2="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwoMrE0aNNuYH5AlJ3B-4PT5UMC2fdAwS19xHVsW-rf_BI__tArA";
    if(image.src==img_source1){
        image.src=img_source2;
        //change anchor default styling for anchor press
        obj.style='pointer-events: none;color:grey';
       //enable anchor default styling for next anchor
        obj.nextElementSibling.style='pointer-events:auto'
    }
    else {
        image.src=img_source1
        obj.style=' pointer-events: none;color:grey';
        obj.previousElementSibling.style='pointer-events:auto'
    }
}
</script>
```

**Add an id for each anchor elements..here is a modified version of your html**

```
<div id="test">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwoMrE0aNNuYH5AlJ3B-4PT5UMC2fdAwS19xHVsW-rf_BI__tArA" />
   <div class="caption">
      <h4>
        <a id='anchor1' href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleImg('test',this)">Image1</a> 
        <a id='anchor2' href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleImg('test',this)">Image2</a>
        </h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

**here is a snippet**

```html
<script>
function toggleImg(charName,obj) {
 var image=document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
 var img_source1= "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7j4zeqZB4theKrjb13e8XwhXXYpumwYEzTvhYclxrSrzS_5yJ";
 var img_source2="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwoMrE0aNNuYH5AlJ3B-4PT5UMC2fdAwS19xHVsW-rf_BI__tArA";
 if(image.src==img_source1){
  image.src=img_source2;
  obj.style='pointer-events: none;color:grey';
  obj.nextElementSibling.style='pointer-events:auto'
 }
 else {
  image.src=img_source1
  obj.style=' pointer-events: none;color:grey';
  obj.previousElementSibling.style='pointer-events:auto'
 }
}
</script>

<div id="test">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwoMrE0aNNuYH5AlJ3B-4PT5UMC2fdAwS19xHVsW-rf_BI__tArA" />
   <div class="caption">
      <h4>
        <a id='anchor1' href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleImg('test',this)">Image1</a> 
        <a id='anchor2' href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleImg('test',this)">Image2</a>
  </h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}

  </script>
```

The HTML

```
    <a href="#" class="bold" onclick="toggle_visibility('caption');">SHOW/HIDE Images</a>

    <div id="caption">Put your images in here and stuff</div>
```

The div will be hidden on load of the page, clicking the SHOW/HIDE Images text will toggle visibility.

I think this is what you were after... :)